# How to get Elements Object from Jsoup selector method

Tags: jsoup

I am so confused with JSoup. I know that I had it working at one point, but now I can't get

it working at all. I've literally created an empty Java Class file with this code in its

main class. It looks like it should would but however that is not the case? It still honestly looks like it's written correctly to me, however I cannot seem to get a valid Elements object for the life of me. :/

```
String data = HTML_DOCUMENT_CODE;

Elements allTexts = Jsoup.parse(data).select(".gc-message-sms-text");

System.out.println("string is: " + allTexts.toString());

System.out.println("size is: " + allTexts.size());
```

Output:

```
Size is: 
size is: 0
```

Comment: Try giving your string a proper document layout including "<html><body></body></html>"

Answer (score 0):

You aren't parsing a complete document but a fragment so maybe this would work better:

```
String data = "<span class=\"gc-message-sms-text\">asdf</span>";
Document doc = Jsoup.parseBodyFragment(data);
Element body = doc.body();
Elements allTexts = body.getElementsByClass("gc-message-sms-text");

System.out.println("string is: " + allTexts.toString());

System.out.println("size is: " + allTexts.size());
```

http://jsoup.org/cookbook/input/parse-body-fragment

Comment: I am trying to parse a complete document, however I don't get back a valid object. So I tried to simplify my code by setting a part of the code as a regular html variable. But this getElementByClass method seems to be a good idea